# How to run bash script while it returns code 0?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, jenkins

I have bash script with many lines of code and I need run it while it returns $? == 0, but in case if it has error I need stop it and exit with code 1?

The question is how to do it?

I tried to use `set -e` command, but Jenkins does not marks build as failed, for him it looks like Success

I also need to get the Error message to show it in my Jenkins log

I managed to get error code(in my case it will be 126), but how to get error message?

```
main file 
fileWithError.sh
rc=$?; if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then 

echo "exit {$rc} ";
fi

fileWithError.sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
echo "Test"
agjfsjgfshgd
echo "Test2"
echo "Test3"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is it "long" because the script itself is many lines of code, or does it run for a "long" time?  Do you want it to terminate with a non-zero status if any command fails, or do you want to run it in a continuous loop, aborting only when an invocation of the script fails?  What do you mean by "it has an error"?  Do you mean that it encounters unexpected input?  Or that one of the commands it calls exits with a non-zero status?  Or that it produces output that is outside of some expected range?  Clarify the question.

Comment: I updated question

Comment: You still haven't answered the many clarifying questions. `set -e` should indeed fail with an error so it sounds like the code which calls yours script is wrong.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks like you're calling a script from another script. Jenkins only sees that you called the secondary script successfully, which technically has an exit code of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the command `set -e` to the beginning of the file

This should look something similar to this

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

#...Your code...
```

Comment: I've tried the same but with #!/bin/bash, it stops my script but for Jenkins build looks like Success

Comment: Maybe try wrapping it in a script that does something that Jenkins treats as an error if the actual script fails 
```#!/bin/sh

bash actual-script.sh
e=$?
if [ $e -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "FAILED with error code $e"
  #do sth that looks like an error to jenkins
  #....
  #exit with error
  exit 2
fi
```

Comment: can you look at goo.gl/WrgV4f Here I have small project to show

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want:

```
 #!/bin/sh 
 while fileWithError.sh; do
     sleep 1; 
 done
 echo fileWithError.sh failed!! >&2
```

Note that if the script is written well, then the echo is
    redundant as fileWithError.sh should have written a decent
     error message already.  Also, the sleep may not be needed, but is useful to prevent a fast loop if the script succeeds quickly.

You can get the explicit return value, but it requires a bit of refactoring.

```
#!/bin/sh
true
while test $? = 0; do fileWithError.sh; done
echo fileWithError.sh failed with status $?!! >&2
```

since the return value of the while script will be the
return value of sleep in the first construction.

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite easy to get an error code only.
How about this ...

```
#!/bin/bash
Msg=$(fileWithError.sh 2>&1) # redirect all error messages to stdout
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] # Not Equal
then 
    echo "$Msg"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

You catch all messages created by `fileWithError.sh` and if the programm returned an error code then you have the error message already saved in a variable.

But this will make a disadvantage, because you will temporary store all messages created by `fileWithError.sh` till the error appears.

You can filter the error message with `echo "$Msg" |tail -n 1`, but its not 100% save.

You should also do some changes in `fileWithError.sh`...
Switch `set -e` with `trap "exit 1" ERR`. this will close the script on errors.

Hope this will help.